# Sort List Object with another objects

Tags: java, sorting, object

Assume I have two Classes

```
public class TestA{
   TestB testB;
   String text;
   SecondTest secondTest;
               .
               .
               .
}

public class TestB{
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

Now I have a List with `TestB` `List<TestB> list1`

If I want to sort the list I can do something like this:

```
list1.sort(Comparator.comparing(TestB::getA)
```

But what if I have a List with `TestA` `List<TestA> list2`
How I sort to a or b (TestB)?

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting question.
I don't know of any Java "native" solution for this kind of deep comparison.
But one idea is to use your own specific Comparator:

```
    List<TestA> list2 = Arrays.asList( new TestA(new TestB(2, 20)),  new TestA(new TestB(1, 10)),  new TestA(new TestB(3, 30)) ); 
    list2.sort( getComparator() );
```

```
    public Comparator<TestA> getComparator() {      
        return new Comparator<TestA>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TestA obj1, TestA obj2) {
                int obj1A = obj1.getTestB().getA();
                int obj2A = obj2.getTestB().getA();
                
                return Integer.compare(obj1A, obj2A);
            }
        };
    }
```

Of couse null values should be handled accordingly.

Comment: thanks, that looks fine. I have an another question, what if i want to sort to b after sorting a?

Comment: There's a solution. Please post another question with this and I'll answer, otherwise would get confusing either post code in the comments or post an answer that is not related to the main topic/question.