# Custom Comparator sort with multiple fields

Tags: java, sorting, object, comparator

Because this question is related to my last one, I will [link it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618329/sort-list-object-with-another-objects/63620053?noredirect=1#comment112506109_63620053).

Suppose I have a class `TestB` with two integers. I would be able to sort `List<TestB> list` on `a` and then on `b` like this:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(TestB::getA).thenComparing(TestB::getB));
```

Now I want to know how to do that with the custom comparator in the last answer.

Comment: The question isn't clear, at least to me. Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom `Comparator` version of `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(TestB::getA).thenComparing(TestB::getB));` is:

```java
list.sort(new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TestB b1, TestB b2) {
        int cmp = b1.getA().compareTo(b2.getA());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = b1.getB().compareTo(b2.getB());
        return cmp;
    }
});
```

Comment: I get this error when i try the code above "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int".

it works with Integer.compare() fine

Comment: @heapoverflow Your code was calling `comparing()`, not `comparingInt()`, leading to the assumption that `a` and `b` were Objects, not *primitives*. If `a` is an `int`, use `Integer.compare(b1.getA(), b2.getA())` instead. Similar for the other primitives, use the `compare()` method on the appropriate class (`Long`, `Double`, ...). --- *FYI:* Although `comparing()` worked for you, using `comparingInt()` would prevent the unnecessary *auto-boxing* of the primitive.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use what I call a custom generic multi-comparator:

```
list2.sort(getComparator( p -> p.getTestB().getA(),
    p -> p.getTestB().getB() ));

private <T> Comparator<T> getComparator( Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>... functions ) {
    
    return new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T obj1, T obj2) {
            
            for (Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>> function : functions) {
                Comparable<T> res1 = (Comparable<T>) function.apply(obj1);
                Comparable<T> res2 = (Comparable<T>) function.apply(obj2);
                
                int result = res1.compareTo((T) res2);
                
                if ( result != 0 ) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

It will sort from left to right regarding the order which function parameters are placed. Warnings will be raised although. Because it's very generic.
Keep in mind that the types of the final values to be compared must implement Comparator (which primitive types like Integer already do) and you should deal with null problems (I didn't do it here to keep it short).

Comment: okay thanks, i was hoping for an elegant and simple solution. i will wait for more answers